# How to find all parts of a string which are not contained in parts of another string?

Tags: c#

I have two strings which I need to check if they have similar values but not identical. The final string should contain all *missing* parts, so the parts of string1 which are not contained in the parts of string2 (completely or as sub-string). How to do that?

For example:

```
string first = "aaa/bbb/cccc/dddd";
string second "bbbb/cccc";
```

The third string should be

```
aaa/dddd
```

Comment: @Liam-not all the value is similar just part of it

Comment: @shopiaT: by *similar* strings people usually consider those which don't have exactly the same letters, like when you misspell a word when doing a Google search (e.g. as in [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)). What you seem to be asking is how to *remove* a specific substring from the source string?

Comment: @Groo: no, actually he wants to find all tokens which are not a sub-string in a second string's tokens(splitted by a separator). The final string should contain the missing tokens concatenated with the original delimiter.

Comment: @Tim: are you sure? I don't see any mention of tokens anywhere. Simply writing `var third = first.Replace(second, "");` would solve the OP's problem (taking presumable typos into account). Unless the result really has `aaaa` instead of `aaa` (before your edit), and the typo was in the last line?

Comment: @shopiaT: i have edited your question to clarify the requirement. If it's not correct you can view your original question in the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25012112/revisions) and edit it again.

Comment: @Groo: i was not 100% sure but he has accepted the answer, so i assume that i've guessed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you actually want to split by `/` and get all tokens which are not in the second string?

```
string first = "aaa/bbb/cccc/dddd";
string[] firstParts = first.Split('/');
string second = "bbbb/cccc";
string[] secondParts = second.Split('/');
var missing = firstParts.Where(t1 => !secondParts.Any(t2 => t2.Contains(t1)));
string third = string.Join("/", missing);
```

The result is `"aaa/dddd"` which is not exactly what you expect. Can you clarify why you expect `"aaaa/dddd"`?